# TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, sqlalchemy

The server that hosts my `db` is in the `U.S`. When I add an item to the `db`, I want the time to be stored using `Australia/Sydney` time. Regardless of what country the user is in, if they retrieve this record, it should be returned using `Australia/Sydney` time. Currently I am doing this:

```
tz = pytz.timezone('Australia/Sydney')
orderDate = datetime.now(tz)
return add_order_to_db(orderID, orderDate, orderCost) # Adds an ORDER object to db
```

The issue arises when I want to update the `orderDate` for the above `ORDER` object.

```
tz = pytz.timezone('Australia/Sydney')
orderDate = datetime.now(tz)

with contextlib.closing(DBSession()) as session:
    try:
        existingOrder = session.query(ORDER).filter_by(ORDERSID=orderID).first()
        existingOrder.ORDERSDATE = orderDate
        session.commit()
    except exc.SQLAlchemyError, error:
        session.rollback()
        raise_database_error(error)
```

**ORDER object**

```
class ORDER(Base):
__tablename__ = 'ORDERS'

ORDERSID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
ORDERSDATE = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
ORDERSCOST = Column(Numeric(19, 4), nullable=False)
```

In `mySQL`, `ORDERSDATE` is a `Datetime` variable.

Comment: it looks like [MySQL-python doesn't support timezone-aware datetime objects](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3136/mysql-doesnt-accept-timezone-offsets-in). You could try to set Australia/Sydney timezone for the MySQL db connection and use naive datetime objects (if TIMESTAMP type is used) or just strip timezone info before putting it into the db and reattaching it while retrieving from the db). Or (better) use naive datetime object to represent UTC time (otherwise some time values can be ambiguous)

Answer (score -1):

How about retaining the offset-naive nature of the datetime object by just applying the offset to the current UTC time?

```
 tz = pytz.timezone('Australia/Sydney')
 orderDate = datetime.datetime.now() +  tz._utcoffset
```

Comment: why would you add the local time (that might be in a different timezone) and the private attribute that may correspond to utc offset in Australia/Sydney at some point in time (it is not necessary that it has *any* relation to the time referred by `datetime.now()`)? btw, `datetime.now(tz)` is the correct way to get the current time in `tz` timezone.